# How to hide certain text in table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, hide

I have a simple table with a few text items:

```
<table>
<tr><td><h3>Foo</h3></td><td>This is Foo</td></tr>
<tr><td><h3>Bar</h3></td><td>This is Bar</td></tr>
</table>
```

How to hide a row where h3 text = Foo ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through each row, and check whether the `.text()` of the `<h3>` returns `"Foo"`. If true, use `.hide()` to hide the row. If you want to remove the node from the tree, use `.remove()` instead.

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.find('h3').text() == 'Foo') $this.hide();
})
```

Comment: If you're dealing with generated markup, it may be worth it to $.trim() the output of text() to deal with whitespace and/or newlines.

Comment: Or in a single line: `$('table h3:contains(Foo)').parents('tr').hide();`

Comment: @gustavotkg That does also match `<h3>This is not Foo</h3>`. I don't think that the OP wants to hide these elements.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Phy/3/) is the link for what you are looking..

```
   $('table tr td').find('h3').filter(
   function()
             { 
                return $(this).html().indexOf('Foo') > -1
             }).parents('tr').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr").find("h3:contains('Foo')").closest("tr").hide();
```

*This will not get an exact match, however.*

Comment: A :contains('Foo') selector will also match <h3>Food</h3>, which may be bad.

Comment: Ah, good point. I didn't know that. Is there a way to get an exact match using this approach?

Comment: You can use closest() this way:

$('table tr h3').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text() === 'Foo') {
        $this.closest("tr").hide();
    }
})

Answer (score 0):

Alternative version of Rob W's answer, trading a find() for a closest():

```
$('table tr h3').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text() === 'Foo') {
        $this.closest("tr").hide();
    }
})
```